# Getting an error in jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[] { user.getUserId(), user.getPassword() }, String.class);

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

cant solve this exception

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.nullableSingleResult(Ljava/util/Collection;)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

```
String sql = "SELECT uname FROM USER_DATA WHERE uid=? AND upass=?";

    try {
        System.out.println("2222222222222");
        String userId = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[] {
                user.getUserId(), user.getPassword() }, String.class);System.out.println("noooooo");

        return userId;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

my versions

spring-boot-starter-parent 1.5.10.RELEASE,spring-boot-starter jdbc,
spring-boot-starter-web,spring-boot-starter-test,spring-boot-starter-tomcat

```
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
                        <version>4.6.1</version>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
                    </dependency>
        <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
    <dependency>
                <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.7</version>
            </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

About lines are in pom which all need to change kindly help

Comment: You are mixing jars from different versions of Spring / Spring Boot. Leading to incompatibility issues. Never mix jars from different versions of a framework that is troubel waiting to happen.

Comment: And i did't specify version for this dependencies spring-boot-starter jdbc, spring-boot-starter-web,spring-boot-starter-test,spring-boot-starter-tomcat .

Comment: Regardless your stacktrace clearly shows that you are mixing versions 5.0.2 and 4.3.4. Remove the `spring-jdbc` dependency as that is already implied by `spring-boot-starter-jdbc`. So you clearly specified a version.